# Unable to Execute Python Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

Despite my best attempt, I am unable to make a dent into getting the required output. I have provided my progress so far (after the question).

Write a class named Patient that has the following data attributes:

> name ( type string), height (type float), has_hair (type
>       Boolean)

The **Patient** class should have an `__init__` method (i.e., an initializer) that accepts the Patient’s `name`, `height`, and `has_hair` as arguments. These values should be assigned to the object's `name`, `height`, and `has_hair` data attributes. By default, `let has_hair = 0`

Each Patient should start with 0 tablets, stored in an attribute tablets.
A `collect_tablets(number)` method adds the given number of tablets to the Patient's number. This function should also be able to be called as `collect_tablets()` which just adds one barange to the total number.

An `eat()` method consumes one tablet from the Patient's total, but increases the height of the Patient by 0.1m. If the Patient does not have any baranges, the method should print

> "I don't have any tablets  to eat!."

A 'feast()' method consumes five tablets from the Patient's total. If the Patient is not hairy when he feasts, he grows hair. If the Patient is already hairy when he feasts, he grows by 50% instead (for example: a 2 m Patient grows to 3 m). 
A bald Patient that feasts, only grows hair, he does not grow in height unless he feasts later. If the Patient does not have enough tablets  for a feast, the method should print

> “I don't have enough tablets  to feast!.”

```
 TEST CASE:
 hungry_patient = Patient("Jack", 1.89)
 hungry_patient.collect_tablets()
 hungry_patient.eat()
 print(hungry_patient)

  OUTPUT
  Jack is a 1.99 m tall blork!
```

My Code is :

```
class Patient:
    def __init__(self, name, height, tablets = 0, has_hair=False):
    """Blork constructor"""
    self.name = name
    self.height = height
    self.tablets = tablets
    self.has_hair = has_hair

  def collect_tablets(self):
    self.tablets = self.tablets + 1

  def eat(self):
    if self.tablets == 0:
        print(“I don't have enough to eat”)
    else: 
        self.tablets = self.tablets - 1
        self.height = self.height + 0.1

  def feast(self):
    if self.tablets >= 5:
        if self.has_hair == True:
            self.height = self.height + 0.5 * (self.height)
        if self.has_hair == False:
            self.has_hair = True
    else:
        print("I don't have enough baranges to feast!")


 hungry_patient = Patient("Jack", 1.89)
 hungry_patient.collect_tablets()
 hungry_patient.eat()
 print(hungry_patient)
```

I am not able to get the program to execute.

Please help and advise me as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: On the line `self.tabletX = self.tabletX – 1` you seem to have an en dash character `–` instead of a standard dash/hyphen/minus character `-`. Is that in your source file or just a copying artefact?

Comment: Dear Darth. ...It is a negative sign. Not an en dash.

Comment: Copy it into Google and see for yourself, it's definitely an en dash as it appears in the question. Same on the line which is commented out.

Comment: You were correct. I have edited and updated the typo. :)

Comment: You have typographic double quotes on line 14. Use a text editor to write code, not a fancy word processor.

Comment: The question is: is it the same in your source file and is that what's causing the error? The UTF-8 representation of an en dash is `0xE2 0x80 0x93`, with 93 mysteriously appearing. Just a coincidence? ;)

Comment: The error was displayed in my Wing IDE. It seems that error messages are notoriously vauge, especially for beginners like me.

Comment: No fancy word processor. :) I used Wing IDE

Comment: Did the error go away after changing the invalid characters we mentioned? If so, this question should be closed as off-topic as it was caused by typos.

Comment: No. The typo was incidental. I am still unable to get any output.

Comment: Hello Darth, I am using a Python editor, and re-examined and removed the fancy quotes in the editor. Also fixed the indentations. Still no execution. Could you please provide the running code? Thanks a lot in advance...as I am still a beginner. Please oblige.

Comment: You still have typographic quotes on line 14. They are clearly distinct from the normal quotes in the docstring and other calls to `print`.

Comment: Can you please add the error message back to the question, so that others with a similar problem can find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are invalid characters in your code. On line 14:

```
print(“I don't have enough to eat”)
```

change the special opening and closing quotes to standard double quotes:

```
print("I don't have enough to eat")
```

After fixing the above and some indentation issues, the code runs, but the output is just a raw string representation of the object instance you're printing.

```
<__main__.Patient instance at 0x7f17180af3b0>
```

In order to define a custom string representation, you need to define an `__str__` and/or `__repr__` method on your class. Have a look at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

```
def __str__(self):
  return "%s is a %s m tall blork!" % (self.name, self.height)
```

Full working code:

```
class Patient:
  def __init__(self, name, height, tablets = 0, has_hair=False):
    """Blork constructor"""
    self.name = name
    self.height = height
    self.tablets = tablets
    self.has_hair = has_hair

  def collect_tablets(self):
    self.tablets = self.tablets + 1

  def eat(self):
    if self.tablets == 0:
        print("I don't have enough to eat")
    else: 
        self.tablets = self.tablets - 1
        self.height = self.height + 0.1

  def feast(self):
    if self.tablets >= 5:
        if self.has_hair == True:
            self.height = self.height + 0.5 * (self.height)
        if self.has_hair == False:
            self.has_hair = True
    else:
        print("I don't have enough baranges to feast!")

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s is a %s m tall blork!" % (self.name, self.height)


hungry_patient = Patient("Jack", 1.89)
hungry_patient.collect_tablets()
hungry_patient.eat()
print(hungry_patient)
```

Comment: Profuse thanks for the code and explanation. But for your help, I would never have figured it out. 
/Jill

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept it as an answer if it was helpful.